# Is there a way to create a css rule for a component that is computed once inside the component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to see if it's possible to define a mat-table's columns dynamically, including the columns' width and alignment.

I can make it work with ngStyle, and if I use a pipe, the code isn't called too often :

```
            <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" matColumnDef="{{column.columnDef}}">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header >
                      {{column.header}}
                  </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="column | styleRow">
                      {{column.cell(row)}}
                  </td>
            </ng-container>
```

Here `styleRow` is a pipe that transforms a row in the column definition list and returns the right css rules for that column; for example

```
    transform(column: ColumnConfig): object {
        const obj = {
            textAlign: column.textAlign,
            width: column.type === 'number' ?
                column.length + 'ch' :
                (column.length * 0.45) + 'rem'
        };
        console.log(column, obj);
        return obj;
    }
```

The thing is, it's still called way to often for my taste, when all I need is something that puts the following rules in the component's stylesheet:

```
        .mat-column-foo {
            width: 7em;
        }

        .mat-column-bar {
            width: 15em;
        }

        .mat-column-baz {
            width: 7em;
            text-align: right;
        }
        // ... and so on.
```

... But I don't know how to do that. In the following example, I would like the setStyles function to either :

- add css rules to to the same style tag where I find the rules defined in test.component.css
- create a new style tag with the rules but I must find the component's _ngcontent_xxxxxx attribute so I can create rules that look like `.mat-column-foo[_ngcontent_xxxxxx] {...}`

```
export interface TblData {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
}

export interface ColumnConfig {
    columnDef: string;
    header: string;
    textAlign: string;
    length: number;
    type: string;
    cell: any;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: TblData[] = [ .... ];

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    columns: ColumnConfig[] = [
        {   columnDef: 'foo',
            header: 'Foo',
            textAlign: 'left',
            length: 10,
            type: 'date',
            cell: (element: any) => `${element.foo}`
        },
        {   columnDef: 'bar',
            header: 'Bar',
            textAlign: 'left',
            length: 50,
            type: 'string',
            cell: (element: any) => `${element.bar}`
        },
        {   columnDef: 'baz',
            header: 'Baz',
            textAlign: 'right',
            length: 7,
            type: 'number',
            cell: (element: any) => `${element.baz}`
        }
    ];
    displayedColumns = ['select', ...this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef)];
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TblData>(ELEMENT_DATA);
    selection = new SelectionModel<TblData>(true, []);
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        // setStyles(columns);  <-- how do I implement this function ?
    }

    .....
```

Full source for the example:

html:

```
<div>
    <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <div class="table_scroll">
            <div class="table_intro">
                <p>
                    Some text above the table.
                </p>
                <p>
                    And more text.
                </p>
            </div>
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

                <!-- Checkbox Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                                      [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
                        </mat-checkbox>
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                                      [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
                        </mat-checkbox>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Dynamic Columns -->
                <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; trackBy: columnId" matColumnDef="{{column.columnDef}}">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                        {{column.header}}
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="column | styleRow">
                        {{column.cell(row) | formatRow:column}}
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <mat-toolbar>
            <mat-toolbar-row>
                <mat-icon title="Export as CSV">table_chart</mat-icon>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <mat-icon title="Export as PDF">print</mat-icon>
                <span class="example-spacer"></span>
                <mat-paginator class="paginator" [pageSizeOptions]="[50, 100, 200]"></mat-paginator>
            </mat-toolbar-row>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';

/**
 * Column definition.
 * columnDef is the key name in the row record
 * header is the text displayed in the column's header
 * textAlign and length are for styling the columns
 * type is for future use
 * cell is a function to get that cell's value from the row.
 */
export interface ColumnConfig {
    columnDef: string;
    header: string;
    textAlign: string;
    length: number;
    type: string;
    cell: any;
}

/**
 * Displayed rows must have a selection label property.
 */
export interface MrmTableRow {
    selection_label: string;
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-mrm-table',
    templateUrl: './mrm-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mrm-table.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MrmTableComponent<T extends MrmTableRow> implements OnInit {
    @Input() columns: ColumnConfig[];
    @Input() data: T[];

    selection = new SelectionModel<T>(true, []);
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
    public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<T>;
    public displayedColumns: string[];

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<T>(this.data);
        this.displayedColumns = ['select', ...this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef)];
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        // setStyles(data);
    }

    /**
     *  returns true if all rows are selected
     */
    isAllSelected() {
        const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
        const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
        return numSelected === numRows;
    }

    /**
     * Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection.
     */
    masterToggle() {
        this.isAllSelected() ?
            this.selection.clear() :
            this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
    }

    /** The aria label (accessibility) for the checkbox on the passed row */
    checkboxLabel(row?: T): string {
        if (!row) {
            return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
        }
        return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ?
            'deselect' :
            'select'} row ${row.selection_label} `;
    }

    /**
     * This for the trackBy in the column loop.
     */
    columnId(index: number, item: ColumnConfig): string {
        return item.columnDef;
    }
}
```

SCSS:

```
.padded {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}



:host > div {

    padding: 10px;

    & > div {
        .mat-toolbar {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        width: 48em;

        .table_intro {
            padding: 25px;
        }
        div.table_scroll {
            height: 600px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

styleRow pipe for reference, but I'd like a solution where I don't need it.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {ColumnConfig} from './mrm-table/mrm-table.component';

@Pipe({
    name: 'styleRow'
})
export class StyleRowPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(column: ColumnConfig): object {
        const obj = {
            textAlign: column.textAlign,
            width: column.type === 'number' ?
                column.length + 'ch' :
                (column.length * 0.55) + 'rem'
        };
        console.log('styleRow', column, obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a way to do what I want.

First I have a name to the table in the template:
 `<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort #table>`

Then I retrieved a reference to the table in the component:
`@ViewChild('table', { read: ElementRef , static: true}) tableRef: ElementRef;`

Finally, I get the attribute used for css rule isolsation, compute the css rules and inject them:

```js
    setStyles(columns: ColumnConfig[]) {
        // Get the specific attribute for the component
        const attrNames: string[] = Array.from(this.tableRef.nativeElement.attributes)
            .map((val: Attr) => val.name)
            .filter((val: string) => val.startsWith('_ngcontent'));

        // Hopefully there should be only 1 attribute that starts with _ngcontent.
        const attr: string =  attrNames[0];

        // Now I can make the css rules
        const css: string = columns.map((col) => {
            const width = col.type === 'number' ?
                col.length + 'ch' :
                (col.length * 0.55) + 'rem';
            return `
                .mat-column-${col.columnDef}[${attr}] {
                    text-align: ${col.textAlign};
                    width: ${width};
                }`;
        }).join('\n');

        // And inject them in the page
        const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        head.appendChild(style);
    }
```

It works; now I have to find a way to remove that style tag in ngOnDestroy.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy) function to the `*ngFor`. If you don't use this to provide some identifier for each column, the whole list is re-rendered every time the list reference changes.

The syntax looks like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; trackBy: getColumnId(column)">
```

It looks like the `getColumnId` method can return `column.columnDef` in your case.

The `styleRow` pipes should then only re-evaluate when the column reference changes for the particular column.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change the number of times StyleRow is called. I'm editing the question to include the full source). Besides, I'd really like to have a solution for injecting css rules.

Comment: I guess you could add a styles property to each column in `ngOnChanges` specifically when the columns collection changes instead of having the logic live in the pipe. I'm not sure how much difference that will make, but maybe it will help debug the unexpected changes being detected. It might be tricky to do that without triggering another round of change detection though.